# Can a linear transformation from one vector space to another be many-to-one?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know this is is possible if the element in the codomain to which multiple elements are being mapped to is the zero vector, but is it possible for a non zero vector in the codomain to have multiple pre images ?

Comment: Yes, and it will necessarily happen when the same thing happens with $\mathbf{0}$.  (Exception made for the constant map.)

Comment: @Randall oh i see it now !!

Comment: It is a good exercise to prove:  assume $T: V \to W$ is linear.  Given any $w \in W$ with $T(v)=w$ (so $w$ is in the range), we have $T^{-1}(w) = v + \mathrm{ker}(T)$.  You are interested in the case when the kernel is non-trivial.

Comment: As a specific example, imagine projecting the 2D plane to the x-axis. Each point on the x-axis has as its preimage the vertical line including it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $Ax = 0$ for some $x \neq 0$ and $y$ is in the range of $A$, say, $y = Az$, then
$$A(z+x) = Az + Ax = y,$$
that is, $z$ and $z+x$ are both mapped to $y$. So whenever multiple elements are mapped to $0$, multiple elements are mapped to any vector in the range of $A$.